# Figuring out a way in C to create strings and populate an array with them

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am using the C programming language. I am trying to construct binary strings of max length 32 (8 bytes), add the constructed string to an array of strings, then repeat over and over again. An issue I'm coming across seems to be that my code, which looks similar to this:

```
char *currentBinaryString = malloc(32)

char *binaryStringArray[100];

for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {

//Call for construction of currentBinaryString here using strcpy

binaryStringArray[i] = currentBinaryString;

}
```

This loop correctly assembles the binary string on each execution, but when it comes time to add the current string into the array, what ends up happening at the end is that there is only one non-null element, binaryStringArray[0], and it contains the very last binaryString that was constructed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to `malloc` memory inside the comment.

Comment: All strings written to currentBinaryString? So you have n pointers to the same string.  You need (as said in the comment above) to have multiple strings and the array pointing to each one of them. binaryStringArray[i] = malloc(32+1)  //Call for construction of binaryStringArray[i]  (32+1 because 32 bytes + one null terminator '\0')